# Trigger a websites file download with python

Tags: python, csv, python-2.7, urllib2

There is a stock screening website called [finviz](http://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=ind_stocksonly,sh_price_o10,ta_change_u,ta_changeopen_u,ta_highlow20d_nh,ta_highlow50d_nh,ta_highlow52w_nh,ta_sma20_pa,ta_sma200_pa,ta_sma50_pa&ft=4&o=-change). You can set up specific parameters for it to screen, and then there is a button in the bottom right corner that lets you export the results as a .cvs file.

I would like to create a script, in python 2.7, that will download and analyze the file. I imagine I can use urllib2 to access the website, but how can I trigger the export, and then read from that resulting file? Using the standard urllib2.urlopen(url).read(), returns an html file for the entire site, and not the export I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out, at least in this case, the export button is really a link to a different url. So where the screener's url might be: http://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=sh_price_u1.
The export version of the url is: http://finviz.com/export.ashx?v=111&f=sh_price_u1.
The second url has the funcitonality of triggering download, so instead of urllib2.urlopen("http://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=sh_price_u1").read() I need
urllib2.urlopen("http://finviz.com/export.ashx?v=111&f=sh_price_u1").read()

Answer (score 1):

This one does the job in python. Have a look. https://github.com/nicolamr/trending-value